# How to migrate Drupal nodes from one installation to another, preserving revision history?

Tags: migrations, version-control, nodes

Is there a good way to export a set of nodes from one Drupal installation, including node revision history, and then to merge these into another Drupal installation, including revision history?

I'm familiar with modules such as [Node Export](http://drupal.org/project/node_export) and [Backup and Migrate](http://drupal.org/project/backup_migrate)...  But `Node Export` doesn't preserve revision history, and `Backup and Migrate` doesn't allow merging (only full table replacement).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can also try [UUID](http://drupal.org/project/uuid) and [UUID Features](http://drupal.org/project/uuid_features), can export both Nodes and Nodes revisions.

Comment: Thanks, @Decipher.  I didn't realize UUID also supports node revisions.  Rad.